# digital modulation

Tags: digital-communications

Theoretically in BPSK signal generation we will multiply the digital signal with the carrier and this output we will call as BPSK signl which is an analog signal. 
    But in OFDM if the data is modulated at the base band by using BPSK we will directly take that BPSK modulated data as 1,-1's which is not an analog signal?
can any one tell me what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

BPSK is, at heart, a digital signal.  It is comprised of +1, -1 symbols.  It is only analog in the sense that when things have to exist in the real world (in this case in radio waves) everything is analog.  Then we have to have things like transitions from one symbol to another, but those are necessary evils, not the raison d'etre of BPSK.